# macOS Monterey find last time Bluetooth mouse was connected

Tags: macos, bluetooth, logs

I have lost my Bluetooth Mouse. I would like to find the last date of connection to know when i last had it.
I already tried `blueutil --recent`
the output does update the time everytime I retry the command and I am sure that I did not connect the mouse.

```
blueutil --info 0C-E4-41-0A-BF-3A
address: 0c-e4-41-0a-bf-3a, not connected, not favourite, paired, name: "Sabine Maus", recent access date: 2021-12-08 17:44:57 +0000
```

**Is there a possibility to get the latest time of connection of the mouse?**
system: macOS Monterey vers 12.0.1